# OSX emulator for windows | For use with ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, macos, ionic-framework, virtual-machine

I´m developing using the ionic framework for a while now and want to start developing for ios, but the cheap ass student i am, i cant afford a macbook.

I Tried using hackintosh system already. it was quite buggy and not suitable for any sort of app creation.

Now i was wondering, is there any way i can develop for ios using either cloud services or emulator software?

And if so. which one should i use? 
Is virtualbox an solution for this?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, i searched but could'nt find any good answer on this topic.

Comment: I believe there're "cloud" emulators, but you still need to build the app on OS X and if you have it the local emulators are often enough. Perhaps a used Mac Mini would be a good option, you can also get familiar with the upgrade options for each model on the Apple site and plan minor upgrades (e.g. RAM and SSD) for it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel xdk (https://software.intel.com/es-es/intel-xdk) has a "web" emulator by iphone and ipad or http://www.macincloud.com/ $1 dlls by hour but you need a fast connection.